# Can I use YAJL iOS framework?

Tags: ios5, yajl

I want to use YAJL-iOS framework in my iOS app. But I m just concerned if Apple would reject the app since they do not allow external frameworks.
Can someone provide some advice on this matter.

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that external frameworks are disallowed?

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-avoid-getting-your-ipad-app-rejected.navId-407186.html refers to using private frameworks. I wasnt sure if private frameworks referred to external frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm this is not a problem at all.
I have few applications out there where I use YAJL-iOS.

The last has been approved around 15 days ago.

If you are referring to the fact that an app cannot use non-public API, it is different from an external framework like YAJL.

Most of the time these libraries are built exclusively on top of iOS functionalities, and just make the life easier for programmers to accomplish common stuff, like parsing JSON.

Others, like Three20, specifically mention that they use non-public API. They also mention though, how to use the whole framework, and therefore disable these calls in order to be approved by Apple.